# How to add or remove records from table on click add button, and send all table rows to controller on submit?

Tags: javascript, jquery, sql, model-view-controller

I'm sharing image of my task:

[image: First of all I'm sharing image of my task]

I have issue that, when I clicked on Add Button all fields data will display in table below, and I want to add multiple products to this table, also if user wants to remove any product from table then clicked on remove button.
After add products when user clicked on submit then all record send to controller method.

I'm sharing some code which I'm trying to do.

View Code

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-12">
    <div class="tile">
        <div>
            <h1><i class="fa fa-th-list"></i> Inventory</h1>
            <p>Issu Products to Unit</p>
        </div>
        @Html.Partial("~/Views/Shared/_ErrorMsgPartial.cshtml")
        <div class="tile-body">
            <span style="color:red; font-weight:bold;">Note: Dont Enter Quantity Morethan Availabale Quantity</span>
            @using (Html.BeginForm("IssueProduct", "Inventory", FormMethod.Post, new { @id = "formPost" }))
            {
                <table class="table table-hover table-bordered">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Product</th>
                            <th>Available Qty</th>
                            <th>Issue Qunatity</th>
                            <th>Unit</th>
                            <th>Description</th>
                            <th>Action</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                @Html.DropDownList("productId", null, "Select One", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control", id = "demoSelect" })
                                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.productId, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                            </td>
                            <td id="GetAvlbQty" style="font-weight: bold;color: red;text-align: center;">
                                @{Html.RenderPartial("GetAvlbQty", Model);}
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.invQty, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", id = "invcQty", @PlaceHolder = "Enter Quantity To Issue" } })
                                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.productId, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.invUnit, new List<SelectListItem>
                                                                                                {
                                                                                                new SelectListItem{Text="Unit A",Value="Unit A"},
                                                                                                new SelectListItem{Text="Unit B",Value="Unit B"},

                                                                                                }, "Select Unit", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control", id = "unit" })

                                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.invUnit, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.invDescription, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", id = "descrip", @PlaceHolder = "Enter Description" } })
                                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.invDescription, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <button type="button" id="btnAdd" class="btn btn-outline-success btn-s classAdd">Add</button>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>

                <table id="tablePost" class="table table-hover table-bordered">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Product</th>
                            <th>Available Qty</th>
                            <th>Issue Qunatity</th>
                            <th>Unit</th>
                            <th>Description</th>
                            <th>Action</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody></tbody>
                </table>
                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-success btn-sm" value="Save" />
            }
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Here is some jQuery code but it just add product to row. Not remove and also not send into controller. I don't need to send data through HIDDEN FIELDS.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            $("#btnAdd").on("click", function () {

                var demoSelect = $("#demoSelect :selected").text();
                var invcAvlbQty = $("#availableQty").val();
                var invcQty = $("#invcQty").val();
                var unit = $("#unit :selected").val();
                var descrip = $("#descrip").val();

                $("#tablePost > tbody").append("<tr><td>" +
                    demoSelect + "</td><td>" + invcAvlbQty + "</td><td>" + invcQty + "</td><td>" + unit + "</td><td>" + descrip + "</td></tr>");
            });
        });
```

How can I resolve this?

Comment: We do not allow questions to be significantly modified because it unfairly invalidates the helpful answers given underneath the question. It also prevents future readers from benefiting from the Q&A already created.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create table from you want to add the record in list-

```
     <div>
         <table>
          <tr>
           <td><input type="text" id="txt1"/></td>
           <td><input type="submit" id="btnAdd" value="Add"/></td>
         </tr>
        </table>
    </div>

    <div>
      <table id="tbldata"> </table>
    </div>

     <div>
       <input type="submit" id="btnsubmit" value="Save"/>
     </div>
```

this function is used for add record in list on button add click

```
    $('#btnAdd').click(function(){
       if (!localStorage.count) {
                    localStorage.count = 0;
                }
                localStorage.count++;
                var num = localStorage.count;   

               var TextVal=$('#txt1').val();
               $('#tbldata').append('<tr id=' + num + '><td>'+TextVal+'</td>
             <td><a 
               href="javascript:void(0)" 
               onclick="Removerow(' + num + ')" >Remove</a></td></tr>')
               })
```

this function is used for remove the row from table in list

```
           function Removerow(id)
              {           
                  $("#"+id+"").remove();     
              }
```

this function is used for get al the record from list added in table

```
      $('#btnsubmit').click(function(){
          GetRecord();
     })

      function GetRecord()
           {
             var table = $("#tbldata");
            //find all table tr value usnig each loop
            table.find('tr').each(function (i, el) {
            var $tds = $(this).find('td'),
            ItemName = $tds.eq(0).val();
            SaveRecord(ItemName);
            }
```

this function is used for save record in db

```
         function SaveRecord(ItemName) {
            $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            dataType: 'json',
            url: "Controllername/actionname",
            data: { _ItemName : ItemName },
            success: function (Data) {                   
                   localStorage.clear();                 

            },
            error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {

            }
          });
        }
```

Hope it will help you.

Comment: bro how to use my all field that i mentioned in my question...

these fields
var demoSelect = $("#demoSelect :selected").text();
                var invcAvlbQty = $("#availableQty").val();
                var invcQty = $("#invcQty").val();
                var unit = $("#unit :selected").val();
                var descrip = $("#descrip").val();

Comment: your GetRecord Method gives error to missing "," or anything else....
please resolve this issue and also tell me that how i get all "td" data and send it to controller on submit. I have mentioned all tds already in my question.
Thank You

Comment: u just used one item but i want all item...
i m not good familiar with this. So please help me out thanx

Comment: You can easily add all record in td then on button submit click it will read all record in loop , it will read the first row then send to controller, then second row and send to controller and so on. If you want to read the second td value in tr then add secondtdvalue= $tds.eq(1).val(), ThirdtdValue=ItemName = $tds.eq(2).val();

Comment: Why it send one by one Value?
i want to send all Values at once.... First save in javascript and send all at once to controller

Comment: i dont want to send this way.
i need all record stored into array than array send to controller at once.

Comment: i want to stored all records at once using array....
if changed this code according to my requirements than its pleasure for me...
also tell me how to catch that array into controller?